# ElevatedButton highlightColor?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-button

I have changed from `RaisedButton` to `ElevatedButton` but now I have a problem with the `highlightColor` function. What is the `highlightColor` by the `ElevatedButton` in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent would be something like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: ...,
  child: ...,
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red), //replace this with your desired color
  ),
)
```

You can play around with other parameters of `ButtonStyle` to achieve the desired effect.